# Best approach to a class that handles graphics

Tags: c++

When I'm programming any kind of application with opengl, direct3d, sdl or any graphics api (games, in general) I have the habit of creating a class named Graphics that have everything needed to draw, load images, initialize window, etc. inside of it. There is an instance of this class inside another class, that is the main class of the program, or game, or anything that is going to use it.

As the years passed, I tried a lot of different approaches to using this, and I would like to know if you guys think some of these are good, or if everything is just useless crap and I should do it another way.

1 - Having an instance of Graphics inside the program class and having a function in the programs class that iterates the objects (game objects, like the player, for example) and call the Graphics methods to draw everything accordingly.

2 - Go passing pointer to Graphics to every single object so each one can have a Draw function and call the appropriate Graphics functions themselves by means of this pointer.

3 - Have everything inside Graphics to be static and eliminate the need of creating an instance of graphics. Then you can call every graphic functions from anywhere.(You would just have a Draw function to each object, just like topic 2)

Thank you.

**Edit**: And what if I make something similar to what iostream does with cout, like, just make a header with 'extern Graphics x;', declare x in a cpp file and, then, call everything from this x. Is this too bad? And if it is, why?

Comment: I think the usual approach is to create some backend-agnostic representation of the world and then traverse that with a renderer.

Comment: You're approaching it from the wrong side whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that a "graphics" class can very well have a state, like, for example, a canvas it is drawing on. Therefore, making it a class is good; by creating a class you can make the same set of functions applicable to different types of "canvases" (opengl, directx, sdl, etc.)

Among your options, I think that option 1 would be the best, but option 2 would be the easiest (and option 3 is horrible, because it makes code dependent on global variables, eliminating reusability of your code - it is the hacker approach :D).

Option 1 is great, because you could write a graphics engine that does intelligent stuff with the things it draws: Assume that you have two objects that share the same textures, but use a different mesh. If programmed appropriately, the graphics engine can call the "draw mesh" functions of both objects with the same render settings, in this case the same texture, which speeds speeding up rendering. This is not possible with option 2, which usually groups draw functions for single object together, leading to more changes to the render settings.

Option 2, however, is easier to implement. If you do not need a lot of render speed, I would go for this one, as it is much less work, and leads to a more logical program structure. To realize option 1, like I explained, an object needs to have "render properties" or such, that need to be matched by the render engine, and different draw routines for different draw settings... very complicated in comparison to an object-draw function that just uses a central set of drawing functions like a Graphics class.

So if you opt for a "large project", choose option 1. For fast results, and if you do not need to draw a lot of things, option 2 is probably better. Usability for options 1 and 2 is similar.

*PS: Sorry for the late edit, but my grammar was horrible in the previous version*

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot, but I'm really confused by how people look at this problem with different eyes. The 3 responses I got up to now are quite different, one from the others.

Comment: Probably, the best answer is: choose what suits you best! You can even go for a hacker approach if it brings you there where you need to be. What concerns your edit: I think it is an ok approach - however, it again depends on your needs. If you "just want to draw something", and are concerned with reusability of the Graphics class, what you suggested is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a fourth option, make Graphics a namespace, not a class.

It doesn't sound like a Graphics is a data type, just a collection of functions.  That's exactly what namespaces are for.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think this is a good idea, but if someone could explain me further, I would like to know a little more. I made it a class because it has data and functions that manipulate them. If I would declare a namespace in a header and then include this header in various cpp files, I would be declaring all those variables again in a lot of files, right? For example, inside Graphics I have a screen_width variable, that is the screen width (no, really?). if i declare a graphics::screen_width in a header and then include this header in to code files, it would be two variables?

Comment: by graphics::screen_width i mean, inside a namespace called graphics

Comment: @user2038014 I suggest you investigate the unnamed namespace.  Static data that the Graphics functions rely on would be placed in the .cpp file in the unnamed namespace.

Comment: What I found about unnamed namespace is that just like static global variables, everything inside is only visible to this one cpp file. With Graphics I want exactly the opposite, because I need to use it from a lot of different files, and every file must access the same data (the same ints that represent screen dimensions, or the same draw surface, etc).. did I got something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble figuring out what a "Graphics" object is. An object in software is analogous to an object in real life, so what would a Graphics object represent?

The way I usually do it is not very different from a standard UI application: I have a Window class that can be instantiated multiple times and a MainWindow class that inherits from Window and is only instantiated once. In that MainWindow class I have all the graphics resources that will be used throughout execution (e.g. the Direct3D device object).

Comment: I find that the "real-world analogy" rule is not really true in general. I tend to think about it more like "If and only if it has some state, it should be a class." I agree that `Graphics` probably shouldn't be a class because it wouldn't have any state - it sounds more like a namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @user1610015. But then, it would be good to have functions that handle things like drawing, etc. so that, if the application is ported to another api, you can just change the contents of those functions, and would not need to change your entire code, as you would if your objects were calling direct3d methods directly. So my question is: would those functions like draw be declared inside the MainWindow class?

Comment: Well you're basically talking about making your code compatible with several graphics APIs, and source-level portability is always a bit of a pain :) There are many ways to do it, none of them very elegant. Your Graphics class is one approach (it would basically be one big wrapper class around the entire API). But whichever method you use, it shouldn't affect the actual design of your program.